Polynomial solution in this paper
I was reading this article, where it is claimed (when I reformulate equation $(6)$ p.11) that the real root of
$$
3y^2 - 2y^3 -u= 0
$$
where $u \in (0,1)$, is
$$
y = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos \left( \frac{\arccos(1-2u)}{3} \right) - \sqrt{3} \sin \left( \frac{\arccos(1-2u)}{3} \right) \right]
$$
but how is this result obtained? I have tried using software like Wolfram and MATLAB but they do not give me results similar to this one. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Edited, My question is more about how this result can be obtained, because in the article they only mention that the solution of the polynomial is that, but I am interested in knowing how the result is obtained. Regards

This question is similar to: Inverse function of y = -2x^3 + 3x^2 (see the end of Claude's answer to this older post), and some other posts.
